# Unused function in external javascript file when referenced in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

## My Code

I am attempting to make an incremental game in a website and I want to store the player data in a player.js file. 
A simpler version of that file looks like...
**player.js**

```js
let player = {
    points: 0,
    clickPower: 1,
}

export default player
```

One of the functions in my `loop.js` file which references the `player.js` file to get and set the player data values is when the player clicks on a button and gains points based on the player's click power

**loop.js**

```js
import player from "./player";

function pointClick(){
    player.points += player.clickPower;
    document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = player.points + " POINTS";
};
```

I reference the `pointClick()` function in the HTML file, which looks like...

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Citioweb de Marty</title>
    <script src="js/player.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loop.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "tracker">
        <label id = "points"> 0 POINTS  </label>
        <label id = "machines"> 0 MACHINES  </label>
        <label id = "pointPresses"> 0 POINT PRESSES  </label>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onclick="pointClick()"> CLICK ME </button>
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="buyMachine()"> BUY POINT MACHINE: <span id="machineCost"> 20 POINTS </span></button>
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="buyPointPress()"> BUY POINT PRESS: <span id="pointPressCost"> 100 POINTS </span></button>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <label id="pps"> 0  POINTS PER SECOND </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## The Problem

I'm using PyCharm IDE and when finding usages of the `pointClick()` function in `index.html` it points to the `loop.js` file as expected

However when I find usages of the `pointClick()` function in `loop.js` it doesn't point back to `index.html`, instead it says "Unused function pointClick"

If I run the index.html in debug and click the button that calls `pointClick()` I get an

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pointClick is not defined
```

If I remove the import statement in `loop.js`

```js
import player from "./player"
```

Then my `pointClick()` function in `loop.js` says it's being referenced in `index.html` but at the same time it says `player.points` is missing an import statement.

I've tried searching the issue for quite sometime now, I eventually gave up and decided to make this post. I'm very new to javascript and HTML, so I apologize if this is a simple fix.

Comment: try to delete the export and import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is being imported as a module and this means that you need to also expose the relevant function to the window object, otherwise it won't be available.

Try adding this in the loop.js file:

```
window.pointClick = pointClick;
```